# SQL Resultset returns a table name with * operator and not when specifying columns

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that selects certain columns into a #table. I then do a `select * from` that `#table` in order to retrieve my results.

My problem is that when I use `SELECT * INTO #tableName` it returns the `#table` name and the results, but when I `SELECT DoodleName INTO #tableName` it returns a blank table name.

I want to use the table name in my code.

This is my C# code:

```
           DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("doodle", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                try
                {
                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        openConnectionString(connection);

                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    dataTable.Load(reader);
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    userConnectionErrorMessage = "Error Retrieving results. " + ex.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                        connection.Close();
                }
```

Here is the stored procedure that returns the #table name:

```
SELECT *
INTO   [#table]
FROM   tblDoodle d
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblRandom r
         ON d.DoodleID = d.DoodleID
WHERE  r.RandomID LIKE 1
       AND d.Active LIKE 0;

SELECT *
FROM   #table;
```

and here is the stored procedure that does not return the #table name:

```
SELECT d.DoodleName
INTO   [#table]
FROM   tblDoodle d
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblRandom r
         ON d.DoodleID = d.DoodleID
WHERE  r.RandomID LIKE 1
       AND d.Active LIKE 0;

SELECT *
FROM   #table;
```

I have no idea how to get this working. I also think it is an interesting enough question. I can probably use a workaround to get this done, but this is bothering me way more than it should.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, or why you are using `LIKE` with integers, or why you have an outer join and then a predicate that turns it back to an inner join.

Comment: why not try: 1) remove the "into [#table] to see what each query returns, and 2) use a real / non-temp table to see if there is a different behavior.